# Does the Google API support the 2-Step Verification process?

Tags: google-api, google-oauth

I read about [2-Step Verification](https://www.google.com/landing/2step/features.html) and it is not clear to me in the Google API's natively support this under the hood.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the user authenticates your application they are going to be shown the 2 factor if they have 2 factor enabled on their account.

There is no way for you to know that though. Google doesn't give us any information as to whether or not the user has 2 fa enabled on their account.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that Google APIs offers out-of-the-box 2FA at the level of REST API calls. 2FA on the Google platform is only used at the level of user authentication, not API authentication, which is managed by OAuth 2.0.

What you can do if you are developing your own API backend is to attach a token generated by an authenticator, like Google Authenticator or Authy to the user id to every request to your API backend, in fact creating a 2FA for your API, the factors being the token and the id, obviously the token needs a proper timeout to be set and maybe additional properties. I don't know if the Google Authenticator platform lets you manage this things, the Authy developer platform, on the other hand, is more flexible.

This article as an example of doing something similar using Authy:
https://developer.ibm.com/apiconnect/2017/06/08/secure-apis-two-factor-auth/

Comment: the acronym API implies that there is no user ...this may apply to client-facing oAuth2 flow only (while that user has 2FA enabled), but not for any service-accounts, which are commonly used.

Comment: Rest API calls that request Oauth2 will still require that the user login and 2fa before they are shown the consent secreen